# Validation error value is not valid: primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Please help me to find the solution.

this is the xhtml code:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{activteBean.act.activiteFamille}" 
    converter="familleAct"
    var="f" required="Une famille est obligatoire" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{activteBean.actFamList}" var="famille" itemLabel="#        {famille.dsgFam}" itemValue="#{famille}"/>  
    <p:column>#{f.refFam}</p:column>  
    <p:column>#{f.dsgFam}</p:column>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

here is my converter:

```java
@FacesConverter(forClass=ActiviteFamille.class,value="familleAct" )
public class ActiviteFamilleConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String code) {
    if (code.trim().equals("")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        ActiviteFamilleDao actFamDao = new ActiviteFamilleDao();
        List<ActiviteFamille> actFamList = actFamDao.findAll();

        for (ActiviteFamille af : actFamList) {
            if (af.getRefFam().equals(code)) {
                return af;
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(((ActiviteFamille) value).getRefFam());
    }
}
}
```

The managed bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "activteBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ActivteBean implements Serializable {

private Activite act = new Activite();
private ActiviteDao actDao = new ActiviteDao();
private List<Activite> actList;
private boolean init;

private ActiviteFamilleDao actFamDao = new ActiviteFamilleDao();
private List<ActiviteFamille> actFamList;


public boolean isInit() {
    act = new Activite();
    actList = actDao.findAll();
    actFamList=actFamDao.findAll();
    return init;
}
....
}
```

and thank you for your help.

Comment: you may try system out in converter methods to see what is send and what is received.

Comment: What question are you asking?

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if the `equals()` method for `ActiveFamille` is not implemented properly.

The error message indicates that the selected (and converted) value does not match any of the elements in your list `activteBean.actFamList`.

Try to debug and set a break point into the equals() method of `ActiveFamille` and try to find out why it does not match.

Comment: So helpful! 

I had the same problem, because I haven't had defined equals() method in my "ActiveFamille" class.

There was a corresponding item on the list, but Object's default equals() was matching objects by reference, not object properties. Instance of ActiveFamille that was produced by converter was a completly new instance, of course.

Comment: In my case, the breakpoints on equals or hashcode never hit !